# Intcode computer in Rust

Tags: rust

This is my first attempt to learn Rust by applying it for a problem that I assume is suitable for the language. It's the Intcode computer from https://adventofcode.com/2019.

I've implemented all the features of the computer, and the result is the following:

```
use crate::ComputeResult::{CanContinue, Halt, WaitingForInput};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let input = "1,0,0,3,1,1,2,3,1,3,4,3,1,5,0,3,2,6,1,19,1,19,5,23,2,9,23,27,1,5,27,31,1,5,31,35,1,35,13,39,1,39,9,43,1,5,43,47,1,47,6,51,1,51,13,55,1,55,9,59,1,59,13,63,2,63,13,67,1,67,10,71,1,71,6,75,2,10,75,79,2,10,79,83,1,5,83,87,2,6,87,91,1,91,6,95,1,95,13,99,2,99,13,103,1,103,9,107,1,10,107,111,2,111,13,115,1,10,115,119,1,10,119,123,2,13,123,127,2,6,127,131,1,13,131,135,1,135,2,139,1,139,6,0,99,2,0,14,0";

    println!("Hello, world, {:?}", str_to_intcode(input));
}

fn str_to_intcode(string: &str) -> Vec<i64> {
    string
        .split_terminator(",")
        .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
        .collect()
}

struct State {
    instruction_pointer: u32,
    intcode: Vec<i64>,
    input: Vec<i64>,
    output: Vec<i64>,
    relative_base: i64,
}

enum ComputeResult {
    Halt,
    CanContinue,
    WaitingForInput,
}

//todo turn into an enumeration instead of using u8 for the parameter modes?
fn parameter_modes(opcode: i64) -> (u8, u8, u8, u8) {
    let a = opcode / 10000;
    let b = (opcode - a * 10000) / 1000;
    let c = (opcode - a * 10000 - b * 1000) / 100;
    let d = opcode - a * 10000 - b * 1000 - c * 100;

    (a as u8, b as u8, c as u8, d as u8)
}

fn state_from_string(string: &str) -> State {
    State {
        instruction_pointer: 0,
        intcode: str_to_intcode(string),
        input: vec![],
        output: vec![],
        relative_base: 0,
    }
}

//todo how to deal with the situation when the state is invalid or the parameter mode isn't supported?
fn get_value(parameter_mode: u8, pointer: u32, state: &State) -> i64 {
    //position mode
    if parameter_mode == 0 {
        let at_index = state.intcode[pointer as usize];
        state.intcode[at_index as usize]
    }
    //immediate mode
    else if parameter_mode == 1 {
        state.intcode[pointer as usize]
    } else if parameter_mode == 2 {
        let at_index = state.intcode[pointer as usize] + state.relative_base as i64;
        state.intcode[at_index as usize]
    } else {
        panic!("parameter mode {} not supported", parameter_mode)
    }
}

fn extend_memory(memory_index: u32, state: &mut State) {
    if memory_index >= state.intcode.len() as u32 {
        state.intcode.resize((memory_index + 1) as usize, 0);
    }
}

fn get_memory_address(parameter_mode: u8, pointer: u32, state: &State) -> i64 {
    //position mode
    if parameter_mode == 0 {
        state.intcode[pointer as usize]
    }
    //immediate mode
    else if parameter_mode == 1 {
        panic!("writing to memory will never be in immediate mode")
    }
    //relative mode
    else if parameter_mode == 2 {
        state.intcode[pointer as usize] + state.relative_base as i64
    } else {
        panic!("parameter mode {} not supported", parameter_mode)
    }
}

fn five_amplifiers_in_sequence(intcode: &str, phase_setting: Vec<i64>) -> i64 {
    computer(intcode, vec![0, phase_setting[0]])
        //todo refactor pop for something immutable?
        .and_then(|mut o| computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[1]]))
        .and_then(|mut o| computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[2]]))
        .and_then(|mut o| computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[3]]))
        .and_then(|mut o| computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[4]]))
        .ok()
        .unwrap()
        .pop()
        .unwrap()
}

fn computer(intcode: &str, input: Vec<i64>) -> Result<Vec<i64>, &str> {
    let mut state = state_from_string(intcode);
    state.input = input;

    loop {
        match compute(&mut state) {
            Ok(r) => match r {
                Halt | WaitingForInput => break Ok(state.output),
                CanContinue => continue,
            },
            //todo refactor the nested match and simplify the error mapping
            Err(_) => break Err("bam"),
        }
    }
}

fn pop_and_send(state: &mut State, rx: &Sender<i64>) -> i64 {
    let mut last = 0;
    loop {
        //todo for future use-cases, this might not be desired behaviour, replace with drain
        match state.output.pop() {
            None => break last,
            Some(v) => {
                last = v;
                rx.send(v)
            }
        };
    }
}

fn five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop(
    intcode: &'static str,
    phase_setting: Vec<i32>,
) -> Option<i64> {
    assert_eq!(
        phase_setting.len(),
        5,
        "phase sequence of length five expected, while {} provided",
        phase_setting.len()
    );

    let (tx_a, rx_a): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_b, rx_b): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_c, rx_c): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_d, rx_d): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_e, rx_e): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();

    let lambda = move |name: &str, tx: Sender<i64>, rx: Receiver<i64>| -> i64 {
        let mut state = state_from_string(intcode);

        loop {
            match compute(&mut state) {
                Ok(r) => match r {
                    Halt => {
                        break pop_and_send(&mut state, &tx);
                    }

                    WaitingForInput => {
                        pop_and_send(&mut state, &tx);

                        match rx.recv() {
                            Ok(v) => {
                                state.input.push(v);
                                continue;
                            }
                            Err(e) => panic!("{} error: {}", name, e),
                        }
                    }

                    CanContinue => continue,
                },
                //todo refactor the nested match and simplify the error mapping
                Err(_) => panic!("{} ",),
            }
        }
    };

    tx_a.send(phase_setting[0] as i64)
        .and_then(|_| tx_a.send(0))
        .and_then(|_| tx_b.send(phase_setting[1] as i64))
        .and_then(|_| tx_c.send(phase_setting[2] as i64))
        .and_then(|_| tx_d.send(phase_setting[3] as i64))
        .and_then(|_| tx_e.send(phase_setting[4] as i64))
        .unwrap();

    let _a = thread::spawn(move || lambda("A", tx_b, rx_a));
    let _b = thread::spawn(move || lambda("B", tx_c, rx_b));
    let _c = thread::spawn(move || lambda("C", tx_d, rx_c));
    let _d = thread::spawn(move || lambda("D", tx_e, rx_d));
    let e = thread::spawn(move || lambda("E", tx_a, rx_e));

    e.join().ok()
}

fn compute(state: &mut State) -> Result<ComputeResult, String> {
    let offset = state.instruction_pointer;

    //todo is this defensive programming a good idea?
    assert!(
        offset < state.intcode.len() as u32,
        "offset {} out of bounds, intcode length {}",
        offset,
        state.intcode.len()
    );
    assert!(state.intcode.len() > 0, "no intcode to process");

    let (a, b, c, opcode) = parameter_modes(state.intcode[offset as usize]);

    //add
    if opcode == 1 {
        let memory_address = get_memory_address(a, offset + 3, state);
        extend_memory(memory_address as u32, state);

        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);
        let second_parameter = get_value(b, offset + 2, state);

        state.intcode[memory_address as usize] = first_parameter + second_parameter;
        state.instruction_pointer += 4;

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //multiply
    else if opcode == 2 {
        let memory_address = get_memory_address(a, offset + 3, state);
        extend_memory(memory_address as u32, state);

        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);
        let second_parameter = get_value(b, offset + 2, state);

        state.intcode[memory_address as usize] = first_parameter * second_parameter;
        state.instruction_pointer += 4;

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //input
    else if opcode == 3 {
        let memory_address = get_memory_address(c, offset + 1, state);

        //attempt to read from the input
        match state.input.pop() {
            Some(v) => {
                extend_memory(memory_address as u32, state);

                state.intcode[memory_address as usize] = v as i64;
                state.instruction_pointer += 2;

                Ok(CanContinue)
            }
            None => Ok(WaitingForInput),
        }
    }
    //output
    else if opcode == 4 {
        let value_to_output = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);

        state.output.push(value_to_output);
        state.instruction_pointer += 2;

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //jump it true
    else if opcode == 5 {
        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);
        let second_parameter = get_value(b, offset + 2, state);

        if first_parameter != 0 {
            state.instruction_pointer = second_parameter as u32;
        } else {
            state.instruction_pointer += 3;
        }

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //jump it false
    else if opcode == 6 {
        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);
        let second_parameter = get_value(b, offset + 2, state);

        if first_parameter == 0 {
            state.instruction_pointer = second_parameter as u32;
        } else {
            state.instruction_pointer += 3;
        }

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //less than
    //todo refactor because the only difference in the logic for opcode 7 and 8 is '<' vs. '==', lambda or something?
    else if opcode == 7 {
        let memory_address = get_memory_address(a, offset + 3, state);
        extend_memory(memory_address as u32, state);

        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);
        let second_parameter = get_value(b, offset + 2, state);
        let value = if first_parameter < second_parameter {
            1
        } else {
            0
        };

        state.intcode[memory_address as usize] = value;
        state.instruction_pointer += 4;

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //equals
    else if opcode == 8 {
        let memory_address = get_memory_address(a, offset + 3, state);
        extend_memory(memory_address as u32, state);

        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);
        let second_parameter = get_value(b, offset + 2, state);
        let value = if first_parameter == second_parameter {
            1
        } else {
            0
        };

        state.intcode[memory_address as usize] = value;
        state.instruction_pointer += 4;

        Ok(CanContinue)
    }
    //adjust relative base
    else if opcode == 9 {
        let first_parameter = get_value(c, offset + 1, state);

        state.relative_base += first_parameter;
        state.instruction_pointer += 2;

        Ok(CanContinue)
    } else if opcode == 99 {
        Ok(Halt)
    } else {
        let error = format!("{} {}", "Unknown opcode", opcode);
        Err(error)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::{
        computer, five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop, five_amplifiers_in_sequence, str_to_intcode,
    };
    use permutohedron::Heap;

    #[test]
    fn can_parse_intcode() {
        assert_eq!(vec![1, 0, 0, 0, 99], str_to_intcode("1,0,0,0,99"));
    }

    #[test]
    fn input_output() {
        assert_output("3,0,4,0,99", Some(55), vec![55])
    }

    #[test]
    fn parameter_modes() {
        assert_output("1002,4,3,4,33", None, vec![])
    }

    fn input_day5() -> &'static str {
        "3,225,1,225,6,6,1100,1,238,225,104,0,1,192,154,224,101,-161,224,224,4,224,102,8,223,223,101,5,224,224,1,223,224,223,1001,157,48,224,1001,224,-61,224,4,224,102,8,223,223,101,2,224,224,1,223,224,223,1102,15,28,225,1002,162,75,224,1001,224,-600,224,4,224,1002,223,8,223,1001,224,1,224,1,224,223,223,102,32,57,224,1001,224,-480,224,4,224,102,8,223,223,101,1,224,224,1,224,223,223,1101,6,23,225,1102,15,70,224,1001,224,-1050,224,4,224,1002,223,8,223,101,5,224,224,1,224,223,223,101,53,196,224,1001,224,-63,224,4,224,102,8,223,223,1001,224,3,224,1,224,223,223,1101,64,94,225,1102,13,23,225,1101,41,8,225,2,105,187,224,1001,224,-60,224,4,224,1002,223,8,223,101,6,224,224,1,224,223,223,1101,10,23,225,1101,16,67,225,1101,58,10,225,1101,25,34,224,1001,224,-59,224,4,224,1002,223,8,223,1001,224,3,224,1,223,224,223,4,223,99,0,0,0,677,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1105,0,99999,1105,227,247,1105,1,99999,1005,227,99999,1005,0,256,1105,1,99999,1106,227,99999,1106,0,265,1105,1,99999,1006,0,99999,1006,227,274,1105,1,99999,1105,1,280,1105,1,99999,1,225,225,225,1101,294,0,0,105,1,0,1105,1,99999,1106,0,300,1105,1,99999,1,225,225,225,1101,314,0,0,106,0,0,1105,1,99999,1108,226,226,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,329,101,1,223,223,107,226,226,224,1002,223,2,223,1005,224,344,1001,223,1,223,107,677,226,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,359,101,1,223,223,7,677,226,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,374,101,1,223,223,108,226,226,224,102,2,223,223,1006,224,389,101,1,223,223,1007,677,677,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,404,101,1,223,223,7,226,677,224,102,2,223,223,1006,224,419,101,1,223,223,1107,226,677,224,1002,223,2,223,1005,224,434,1001,223,1,223,1108,226,677,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,449,101,1,223,223,108,226,677,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,464,1001,223,1,223,8,226,677,224,1002,223,2,223,1005,224,479,1001,223,1,223,1007,226,226,224,102,2,223,223,1006,224,494,101,1,223,223,1008,226,677,224,102,2,223,223,1006,224,509,101,1,223,223,1107,677,226,224,1002,223,2,223,1006,224,524,1001,223,1,223,108,677,677,224,1002,223,2,223,1005,224,539,1001,223,1,223,1107,226,226,224,1002,223,2,223,1006,224,554,1001,223,1,223,7,226,226,224,1002,223,2,223,1006,224,569,1001,223,1,223,8,677,226,224,102,2,223,223,1006,224,584,101,1,223,223,1008,677,677,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,599,101,1,223,223,1007,226,677,224,1002,223,2,223,1006,224,614,1001,223,1,223,8,677,677,224,1002,223,2,223,1005,224,629,101,1,223,223,107,677,677,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,644,101,1,223,223,1108,677,226,224,102,2,223,223,1005,224,659,101,1,223,223,1008,226,226,224,102,2,223,223,1006,224,674,1001,223,1,223,4,223,99,226"
    }

    #[test]
    fn day5_part_one() {
        assert_output(
            input_day5(),
            Some(1),
            vec![0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11049715],
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn day5_part_two() {
        assert_output(input_day5(), Some(5), vec![2140710])
    }

    fn input_day7() -> &'static str {
        "3,8,1001,8,10,8,105,1,0,0,21,42,67,84,97,118,199,280,361,442,99999,3,9,101,4,9,9,102,5,9,9,101,2,9,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,99,3,9,101,5,9,9,102,5,9,9,1001,9,5,9,102,3,9,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,99,3,9,1001,9,5,9,1002,9,2,9,1001,9,5,9,4,9,99,3,9,1001,9,5,9,1002,9,3,9,4,9,99,3,9,102,4,9,9,101,4,9,9,102,2,9,9,101,3,9,9,4,9,99,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,101,2,9,9,4,9,99,3,9,1001,9,1,9,4,9,3,9,101,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,101,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,101,1,9,9,4,9,3,9,101,2,9,9,4,9,99,3,9,101,1,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,1,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,101,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,99,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,101,1,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,99,3,9,101,1,9,9,4,9,3,9,101,1,9,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,1002,9,2,9,4,9,3,9,101,1,9,9,4,9,3,9,102,2,9,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,1,9,4,9,3,9,1001,9,2,9,4,9,99"
    }

    #[test]
    fn day7_examples() {
        assert_eq!(
            five_amplifiers_in_sequence(
                "3,15,3,16,1002,16,10,16,1,16,15,15,4,15,99,0,0",
                vec![4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
            ),
            43210
        );

        assert_eq!(
            five_amplifiers_in_sequence(
                "3,23,3,24,1002,24,10,24,1002,23,-1,23,101,5,23,23,1,24,23,23,4,23,99,0,0",
                vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
            ),
            54321
        );

        assert_eq!(
            five_amplifiers_in_sequence(
                "3,31,3,32,1002,32,10,32,1001,31,-2,31,1007,31,0,33,1002,33,7,33,1,33,31,31,1,32,31,31,4,31,99,0,0,0",
                vec![1, 0, 4, 3, 2]
            ),
            65210
        );

        assert_eq!(
            five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop("3,26,1001,26,-4,26,3,27,1002,27,2,27,1,27,26,27,4,27,1001,28,-1,28,1005,28,6,99,0,0,5", 
                                               vec![9, 8, 7, 6, 5]),
            Some(139629729));

        assert_eq!(
            five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop("3,52,1001,52,-5,52,3,53,1,52,56,54,1007,54,5,55,1005,55,26,1001,54,-5,54,1105,1,12,1,53,54,53,1008,54,0,55,1001,55,1,55,2,53,55,53,4,53,1001,56,-1,56,1005,56,6,99,0,0,0,0,10", 
                                               vec![9, 7, 8, 5, 6]),
            Some(18216))
    }

    #[test]
    fn day7_part_two() {
        let mut data = vec![5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
        let heap = Heap::new(&mut data);

        let mut permutations = Vec::new();
        for data in heap {
            permutations.push(data.clone());
        }

        let mut res: Vec<i64> = permutations
            .into_iter()
            .map(|phase_setting| {
                five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop(input_day7(), phase_setting).unwrap()
            })
            .collect();

        res.sort();

        assert_eq!(*res.last().unwrap(), 70602018)
    }

    fn input_day9() -> &'static str {
        "1102,34463338,34463338,63,1007,63,34463338,63,1005,63,53,1102,3,1,1000,109,988,209,12,9,1000,209,6,209,3,203,0,1008,1000,1,63,1005,63,65,1008,1000,2,63,1005,63,904,1008,1000,0,63,1005,63,58,4,25,104,0,99,4,0,104,0,99,4,17,104,0,99,0,0,1102,1,30,1010,1102,1,38,1008,1102,1,0,1020,1102,22,1,1007,1102,26,1,1015,1102,31,1,1013,1102,1,27,1014,1101,0,23,1012,1101,0,37,1006,1102,735,1,1028,1102,1,24,1009,1102,1,28,1019,1102,20,1,1017,1101,34,0,1001,1101,259,0,1026,1101,0,33,1018,1102,1,901,1024,1101,21,0,1016,1101,36,0,1011,1102,730,1,1029,1101,1,0,1021,1102,1,509,1022,1102,39,1,1005,1101,35,0,1000,1102,1,506,1023,1101,0,892,1025,1101,256,0,1027,1101,25,0,1002,1102,1,29,1004,1102,32,1,1003,109,9,1202,-3,1,63,1008,63,39,63,1005,63,205,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,207,4,187,1002,64,2,64,109,-2,1208,-4,35,63,1005,63,227,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,229,4,213,1002,64,2,64,109,5,1206,8,243,4,235,1106,0,247,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,14,2106,0,1,1105,1,265,4,253,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,-25,1201,4,0,63,1008,63,40,63,1005,63,285,1106,0,291,4,271,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,14,2107,37,-7,63,1005,63,313,4,297,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,313,1002,64,2,64,109,-7,21101,40,0,5,1008,1013,37,63,1005,63,333,1105,1,339,4,319,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,-7,1207,0,33,63,1005,63,355,1106,0,361,4,345,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,7,21102,41,1,9,1008,1017,41,63,1005,63,387,4,367,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,387,1002,64,2,64,109,-1,21102,42,1,10,1008,1017,43,63,1005,63,411,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,413,4,393,1002,64,2,64,109,-5,21101,43,0,8,1008,1010,43,63,1005,63,435,4,419,1106,0,439,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,16,1206,3,455,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,457,4,445,1002,64,2,64,109,-8,21107,44,45,7,1005,1017,479,4,463,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,479,1002,64,2,64,109,6,1205,5,497,4,485,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,497,1002,64,2,64,109,1,2105,1,6,1105,1,515,4,503,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,-10,2108,36,-1,63,1005,63,535,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,537,4,521,1002,64,2,64,109,-12,2101,0,6,63,1008,63,32,63,1005,63,561,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,563,4,543,1002,64,2,64,109,25,21108,45,46,-2,1005,1018,583,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,585,4,569,1002,64,2,64,109,-23,2108,34,4,63,1005,63,607,4,591,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,607,1002,64,2,64,109,3,1202,7,1,63,1008,63,22,63,1005,63,633,4,613,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,633,1002,64,2,64,109,12,21108,46,46,3,1005,1015,651,4,639,1106,0,655,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,-5,2102,1,-1,63,1008,63,35,63,1005,63,679,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,681,4,661,1002,64,2,64,109,13,21107,47,46,-7,1005,1013,701,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,703,4,687,1002,64,2,64,109,-2,1205,2,715,1106,0,721,4,709,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,17,2106,0,-7,4,727,1105,1,739,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,-23,2107,38,-6,63,1005,63,759,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,761,4,745,1002,64,2,64,109,-3,1207,-4,40,63,1005,63,779,4,767,1105,1,783,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,-8,2101,0,-1,63,1008,63,35,63,1005,63,809,4,789,1001,64,1,64,1105,1,809,1002,64,2,64,109,-6,2102,1,8,63,1008,63,32,63,1005,63,835,4,815,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,835,1002,64,2,64,109,6,1201,5,0,63,1008,63,37,63,1005,63,857,4,841,1106,0,861,1001,64,1,64,1002,64,2,64,109,2,1208,0,32,63,1005,63,883,4,867,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,883,1002,64,2,64,109,23,2105,1,-2,4,889,1001,64,1,64,1106,0,901,4,64,99,21102,27,1,1,21101,0,915,0,1106,0,922,21201,1,55337,1,204,1,99,109,3,1207,-2,3,63,1005,63,964,21201,-2,-1,1,21101,0,942,0,1105,1,922,21202,1,1,-1,21201,-2,-3,1,21102,957,1,0,1105,1,922,22201,1,-1,-2,1106,0,968,21201,-2,0,-2,109,-3,2105,1,0"
    }

    #[test]
    fn relative_base() {
        assert_output(
            "109,1,204,-1,1001,100,1,100,1008,100,16,101,1006,101,0,99",
            None,
            vec![
                109, 1, 204, -1, 1001, 100, 1, 100, 1008, 100, 16, 101, 1006, 101, 0, 99,
            ],
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn large_numbers() {
        assert_output("104,1125899906842624,99", None, vec![1125899906842624]);
        assert_output(
            "1102,34915192,34915192,7,4,7,99,0",
            None,
            vec![1219070632396864],
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn day9_part_one() {
        assert_output(input_day9(), Some(1), vec![3765554916])
    }

    fn assert_output(intcode: &str, input: Option<i64>, expected_output: Vec<i64>) {
        assert_eq!(
            computer(intcode, input.map_or(vec![], |v| vec![v])).unwrap(),
            expected_output
        )
    }

    #[test]
    fn day9_part_two() {
        assert_output(input_day9(), Some(2), vec![76642])
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any input on how to improve the code and make it more Rusty.

I also have a few specific questions:

- Is it a common practice to validate function input in Rust, like I did in `five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop` for example?
- The `pop_and_send` function does two things instead of one: it not only empties a vector, but it sends the last value to a channel. What would be a better way to break this down?
- In `five_amplifiers_in_sequence` I'm "chaining" five computers in sequence and pass on the output from one computer to the next one. Is there a way to further abstract this, maybe my choice for `State` can be improved?
- In `five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop` I attempted multithreading in Rust. Is this the way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever heard of the type state pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is quite a lot of code, and fun to review.

Let's start with the big picture.

## Code organization

The general organization of the code can be improved.  In its current
form, the code is scattered in a bunch of functions, some of which are
hard to understand without context.  The order of functions is also a
bit puzzling.

I would envision an interface along the lines of: (naming and other
details here are quite arbitrary)

- `pub mod Intcode`

  - `pub struct Program`

    - `pub fn parse_from` — corresponding to `str_to_intcode`
  - `pub struct Computer { instruction_pointer: usize, ... }`

    - `pub fn new` — constructs a computer (with settings, if
      any)
    - `pub fn compute` — takes a program, executes it, and
      returns the result
    - private helper functions
  - `pub fn execute` — combines all steps in one for convenience

and other necessary items.  Now, instead of passing `State`s
everywhere, the functions become methods and associated functions of
the `Computer` struct.

I would probably start the development with something like this, and
gradually refine it as I complete the code.

## Error handling

Instead of `&str` and `String`, it is preferable to raise proper error
classes and embed the error message in its `Display` implementation.
See [Why do many exception messages not contain useful details?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/278949)

I recommend using the [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.38/anyhow/) crate to handle errors.  It
removes a lot of boilerplate and simplifies the propagation of errors.

## Naming

The naming throughout your code also leaves room for improvement; I'll
touch on this later.

## Types

Personally, I would type aliases to clarify the meaning of types like
`i64`, `u8`, etc.:

```rust
type Word = i64;
type ParameterMode = u8;
```

For memory indexes, `usize` seems to be a better fit than `u32`, as
you are spamming `as usize` everywhere.

## Details

Now let's go through the code and pay attention to the details.

---

```rust
use crate::ComputeResult::{CanContinue, Halt, WaitingForInput};
```

Glob-imports (or variations thereof), especially global ones, are
generally considered bad form (with some exceptions).

---

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};
use std::thread;
```

These `use` declarations can be condensed:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender},
    thread,
};
```

The [`self`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/paths.html?highlight=path#self) keyword resolves to the current module in a path
— in this case, `std::sync::mpsc`.

---

```rust
fn main() {
    let input = /* ... */;

    println!("Hello, world, {:?}", str_to_intcode(input));
}
```

The `main` function is supposed to be the entry point to a binary.  In
your code, it looks like the remnant of debugging.  Simply remove it
if your code is intended as a library.

---

```rust
fn str_to_intcode(string: &str) -> Vec<i64> {
    string
        .split_terminator(",")
        .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
        .collect()
}
```

Seeing as you used `split_terminator` instead of the regular `split`
here, are you sure that the last number, which isn't followed by a
comma, does not count as part of the program?  If so, it might make
sense to explicitly indicate this in the code.

---

```rust
struct State {
    instruction_pointer: u32,
    intcode: Vec<i64>,
    input: Vec<i64>,
    output: Vec<i64>,
    relative_base: i64,
}
```

As I mentioned before, it makes sense to expand this into a
full-fledged `Computer` struct.

---

```rust
enum ComputeResult {
    Halt,
    CanContinue,
    WaitingForInput,
}
```

`Status` might be a better name.  Also, perhaps `Halt / Success / Blocked`?

---

```rust
//todo turn into an enumeration instead of using u8 for the parameter modes?
```

I agree.

---

```rust
fn extend_memory(memory_index: u32, state: &mut State) {
    if memory_index >= state.intcode.len() as u32 {
        state.intcode.resize((memory_index + 1) as usize, 0);
    }
}
```

Following the precedent set by the standard library, `reserve` may be
more descriptive than `extend`.

---

```rust
fn five_amplifiers_in_sequence(intcode: &str, phase_setting: Vec<i64>) -> i64 {
    computer(intcode, vec![0, phase_setting[0]])
        //todo refactor pop for something immutable?
        .and_then(|mut o| {
            computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[1]])
        })
        .and_then(|mut o| {
            computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[2]])
        })
        .and_then(|mut o| {
            computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[3]])
        })
        .and_then(|mut o| {
            computer(intcode, vec![o.pop().unwrap(), phase_setting[4]])
        })
        .ok()
        .unwrap()
        .pop()
        .unwrap()
}
```

Phew ... are you sure you don't want a loop here?

I assume there is a logic to the number `5` here.  Consider using a
`const` to signify.

---

```rust
fn computer(intcode: &str, input: Vec<i64>) -> Result<Vec<i64>, &str> {
    let mut state = state_from_string(intcode);
    state.input = input;

    loop {
        match compute(&mut state) {
            Ok(r) => match r {
                Halt | WaitingForInput => break Ok(state.output),
                CanContinue => continue,
            },
            //todo refactor the nested match and simplify the error mapping
            Err(_) => break Err("bam"),
        }
    }
}
```

The error handling seems sub-optimal.  Also, the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) is
handy.

---

```rust
fn pop_and_send(state: &mut State, rx: &Sender<i64>) -> i64 {
    let mut last = 0;
    loop {
        //todo for future use-cases, this might not be desired behaviour, replace with drain
        match state.output.pop() {
            None => break last,
            Some(v) => {
                last = v;
                rx.send(v)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Basically [`inspect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.inspect) + [`last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.last).

---

```rust
fn five_amplifiers_in_a_feedback_loop(
    intcode: &'static str,
    phase_setting: Vec<i32>,
) -> Option<i64> {
    assert_eq!(
        phase_setting.len(),
        5,
        "phase sequence of length five expected, while {} provided",
        phase_setting.len()
    );

    let (tx_a, rx_a): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_b, rx_b): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_c, rx_c): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_d, rx_d): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();
    let (tx_e, rx_e): (Sender<i64>, Receiver<i64>) = mpsc::channel();

    let lambda = move |name: &str, tx: Sender<i64>, rx: Receiver<i64>| -> i64 {
        let mut state = state_from_string(intcode);

        loop {
            match compute(&mut state) {
                Ok(r) => match r {
                    Halt => {
                        break pop_and_send(&mut state, &tx);
                    }

                    WaitingForInput => {
                        pop_and_send(&mut state, &tx);

                        match rx.recv() {
                            Ok(v) => {
                                state.input.push(v);
                                continue;
                            }
                            Err(e) => panic!("{} error: {}", name, e),
                        }
                    }

                    CanContinue => continue,
                },
                //todo refactor the nested match and simplify the error mapping
                Err(_) => panic!("{} ",),
            }
        }
    };

    tx_a.send(phase_setting[0] as i64)
        .and_then(|_| tx_a.send(0))
        .and_then(|_| tx_b.send(phase_setting[1] as i64))
        .and_then(|_| tx_c.send(phase_setting[2] as i64))
        .and_then(|_| tx_d.send(phase_setting[3] as i64))
        .and_then(|_| tx_e.send(phase_setting[4] as i64))
        .unwrap();

    let _a = thread::spawn(move || lambda("A", tx_b, rx_a));
    let _b = thread::spawn(move || lambda("B", tx_c, rx_b));
    let _c = thread::spawn(move || lambda("C", tx_d, rx_c));
    let _d = thread::spawn(move || lambda("D", tx_e, rx_d));
    let e = thread::spawn(move || lambda("E", tx_a, rx_e));

    e.join().ok()
}
```

Again, consider using loops.  Most of the `match`es can also be
eliminated using the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) or [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect).

---

```rust
fn compute(state: &mut State) -> Result<ComputeResult, String> {
    let offset = state.instruction_pointer;

    //todo is this defensive programming a good idea?
    assert!(
        offset < state.intcode.len() as u32,
        "offset {} out of bounds, intcode length {}",
        offset,
        state.intcode.len()
    );
    assert!(state.intcode.len() > 0, "no intcode to process");

    let (a, b, c, opcode) = parameter_modes(state.intcode[offset as usize]);

    // ...
}
```

Is it a good idea?  If you consider this to be the logical place to
validate the internal state, then go ahead.  With proper
encapsulation, however, the check can be safety elided (or changed to
`debug_assert!`) if the code is refactored to make class invariants.

Also, `opcode` does not look like a parameter mode.

This entire `compute` function is too long; break it down into smaller
functions.  Also, addition and multiplication can be merged by passing
an argument that determines the operation to use; the same applies to
some other operations.

---

I didn't go into the details to save space, so feel free to ping me if
you find any part of this unclear.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I appreciate the time and attention you've put into reviewing my code. I'll make an attempt to improve it based on your remarks.

Comment: @NikolaKasev That's great to hear :) If you find my answer helpful, you can accept it to remove the question from the unanswered pool.